# Nativescript: Angular2 ListView not updating while using observables

Tags: angular, nativescript

I have an external `API` that returns a list. I have the following in service

```
load() {
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append("Authorization", Config.token);

    return this._http.get(Config.apiUrl + "grocery/list", {headers: headers})
        .map(res => res.json())
        .map(data => {
            let groceryList = [];
            data.list.forEach((grocery) => {
                groceryList.push(new Grocery(grocery._id, grocery.name));
            });
            return groceryList;
        })
        .catch(this.handleErrors);
}
```

I have the following code in component:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this._groceryService.load()
        .subscribe(loadedGroceries => {
            loadedGroceries.forEach((groceryObject) => {
                console.dir(groceryObject);
                this.groceryItems.unshift(groceryObject);
            });
        });

    // It works if I uncomment this. It will just render one item, still nothing from API
    // this.groceryItems.unshift(new Grocery('iuiu', 'jjjjj'));
}
```

If I uncomment the final line above it is rendering on the `ListView`. My `ListView` is templated away and look like below:

```
<GridLayout>
  <ListView [items]="groceryItems" class="small-spacing">
    <template let-item="item">
      <Label [text]="item.name" class="medium-spacing"></Label>
   </template>
  </ListView>
</GridLayout>
```

The API returns something like this:

```
{
  "success": true,
  "msg": "Lists found!",
  "list": [
    {
      "_id": "574a324a18cadad00665a7f3",
      "name": "Carrot",
      "userid": "57482f309ae6c358703066ca",
      "completed": 0,
      "__v": 0
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Hey Deepak, I’m not sure specifically what‘s going wrong here, but I’ve hit this sort of issue as well. You may want to consider switching over to an RxJS Observable for your list as well as the async pipe. That just seems to be the way Angular wants this sort of thing implemented, and I’ve had better luck with that approach. The Groceries repo’s “angular” branch has a sample implementation you can take a look at https://github.com/NativeScript/sample-Groceries/tree/angular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Just a hint**

Using `map` instead of `forEach()` and `push()` should do the same but more concise:

```
load() {
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append("Authorization", Config.token);

    return this._http.get(Config.apiUrl + "grocery/list", {headers: headers})
        .map(res => res.json())
        .map(data => 
          data.list.map(grocery => new Grocery(grocery._id, grocery.name))
        )
        .catch(this.handleErrors);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could add this line after you call the load method `setTimeout(() => {this.cd.markForCheck();}, 0);`. This will allow ListView to be update every time you are pushing new item to the  array. I am attaching below some code snippets:

`import {Component, Input, ChangeDetectionStrategy, ChangeDetectorRef} from "@angular/core"; 
import {Http, Headers, Response, ResponseOptions, HTTP_PROVIDERS} from "@angular/http"; 
import {Observable, BehaviorSubject} from "rxjs/Rx";`

```
constructor(private _http: Http, private cd: ChangeDetectorRef){

         this.groceryItems=[];
    }



 ngOnInit() {
      this.groceryItems.push(new Grocery( '3','test', false, false));
      this.load()
            .subscribe(loadedGroceries => {
                loadedGroceries.forEach((groceryObject) => {
                    this.groceryItems.push(new Grocery( '3',groceryObject.name, false, false));
                    console.log(this.groceryItems.length);
                    console.log(groceryObject.name);
                });
                this.cd.markForCheck();
            });
  }
```

Comment: Why do you think `setTimeout()` is needed for the call to `cd.markForCheck()`?

Comment: `this.cd.markForCheck()` is already to notify about changes. `setTimeout()` by itself also notifies about changes. This seems redundant, especially with default `ChangeDetectionStrategy`.

Comment: You are right. I tested my project ones again and it looks that `this.cd.markForCheck()` works correctly without `setTimeout()`.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback!